# Swift nested generic parameter inference

Tags: swift, generics, type-inference

Swift 5.1 .
Consider the following code.  I don't have a *problem*, exactly, but my code is a little redundant and it's kinda annoying, so I'm wondering if there's a way to tell Swift to infer one of the generic parameters.

```
public class X0 {
}
public class X1: X0 {
}

public class C0<CONTAINED> {
    public var value: CONTAINED

    public init(_ value: CONTAINED) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

public class C1<T: X0>: C0<T> {
}

//public class CA<BOX: C0> { // ERROR Reference to generic type 'C0' requires arguments in <...>
public class CA<BOX: C0<T>, T> { // It's inconvenient that I have to give T as a parameter of the outer class; seems like it could be inferred
}

public func test() {
//    let v: CA<C1<X1>> // ERROR Generic type 'CA' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1, but expected 2)
    let v: CA<C1<X1>, X1> // This here is a little inconvenient to type, particularly when the class names are longer.
}
```

The two `X1` have to be equal, it seems - I tried `CA<C1<X0>,X1>` and `CA<C1<X1>,X0>` just in case there was some logical gotcha I missed, but it gave me errors for both, so I think the two are required to be exactly equal, so inference should be theoretically permitted, at least.

Is there a way to tell Swift to infer the duplicate type parameter?  I tried `_` in a few places, and omitting the parameter, but it gave me errors.

Comment: Are you 100% set on using classes? You would save yourself a lot of headache if you incorporated some protocols into the mix.

Comment: looks like an issue with design. If you have 2 levels of generics, it's like using `Any` pretty much... So like rob said, consider using interfaces and extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can only clean it up with protocols.
2. You can't put protocols inside of types so the naming has to look like Objective-C.
3. Use camel case!

```swift
public class C0<> {
  public var value: 

  public init(_ value: ) {
    self.value = value
  }
}

public protocol C0Protocol {
  associatedtype 
}

extension C0: C0Protocol { }

public class CA<C0: C0Protocol> { }

public func test() {
  let v: CA< C1<X1> >
}
```

Comment: Well...I suppose that's as good as I'm liable to get.  Thanks